# Retrieving items from firebase and dynamiccaly populating it in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am pretty new in react-native, and currently having troubles with this issue. I am trying to get a list of objects from firebase and into react native, but I am getting the error message "Nothing was returned from render"

I have a nested firebase call. The outer one gets a list of group names, and the inner one retrieves group information, as an object, and is called for each group. I am only able to see the groups when the app reloads a second time.

```
function GroupCard(props){
  console.log("Card View")
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{props.name} </Text>
      <Text>{props.members} Memebers</Text>
      <Text>{props.meetings} Meetings</Text>
    </View>
  );
} 

function PopulateGroups(props){

  var bool  = false;
  var detail;
  if(props.user){
    let userId = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    Firebase.database().ref('Users/'+userId).on('value', (snapshot)=>{
             
      if(snapshot.exists){
          console.log(snapshot.val().groups);
          let groups = snapshot.val().groups;
          if(groups!=null){
            groups.map(group=>{
              console.log("Group Name: "+group);
              Firebase.database().ref().child('Groups').child(group).child('Group Description').on('value', (snapshot)=>{
            
                if(snapshot.exists){
                  detail = snapshot.val();
                  console.log("Group Detail: "+ snapshot.val().groupName);
                  bool = true;
        
                }

               });

              });
          }

      }

    });

 
  }

  if(bool){
    return(<View><GroupCard name={detail.groupName} members={detail.members.length} meetings='0'/></View>);  
  }
  else{
    console.log("Hereeee!!!!");
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>User Has No Groups</Text>
      </View>
     );
  }
 
}

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
      user:false,
    }


    componentDidMount(){

          Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
            if(user){
              console.log("Hello");
              this.setState({user:true});
            }
            else{
              console.log("Sign In!!!!!!!");
              this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
            }

          })


    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Button title="Settings" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}></Button>
                <Text>Welcome to your home page</Text>
                <PopulateGroups user={this.state.user}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `detail = snapshot.val()` runs, the `if(bool){` has long since finished.

For this reason you need to store the data you want to render in the state, either by using a `useState` hook, or by calling `setState`.

Something like this:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
      user:false,
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        if(user){
          this.setState({user:true});
          loadGroups(user);
        }
        else{
          this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
        }
      })
    }

    function loadGroups(props){
      if(props.user){
        let userId = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        Firebase.database().ref('Users/'+userId).on('value', (snapshot)=>{             
          if(snapshot.exists){
            let groups = snapshot.val().groups;
            if(groups!=null){
              groups.map(group=>{
                Firebase.database().ref().child('Groups').child(group).child('Group Description').on('value', (snapshot)=>{
                  if(snapshot.exists){
                    this.setState({ detail: snapshot.val() });
                  }
                });
              });
            }
          }
        }); 
      }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Button title="Settings" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}></Button>
                <Text>Welcome to your home page</Text>
                <PopulateGroups user={this.state.user}/>
            </View>
            <View>
                <GroupCard name={detail.groupName} members={detail.members.length} meetings='0'/>
            </View>);  
        )
    }
};
```