# posts are not in order. want to show latest post at top first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a facebook clone, on my home Feed, I want to show all posts,  this code shows posts but not in order, want to show the latest post first.
but now this  is showing (old post (which were already loaded) in descending order and after that all new post in correct order )

## homeFeed.js

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import './stylesheets/HomeFeed.css';
import HomeReels from './HomeReels'
import CreatePost from './CreatePost';
import Post from './Post';
import { ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";
import { realtimedb } from '../firebaseConfiguration';

export default function HomeFeed() {
    const [postdata, setpostdata] = useState([])
 
       
        const starCountRef =  ref(realtimedb, 'Posts/');
        // get post from realtime database
          
        useEffect(()=>{
            onValue(starCountRef, async (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                          var captions=[];

//data is stored in raltime db firebase as ----> Post > uid > timestamp >{caption:"captions"}    
                        //  conver objects to  array , to store strings in final array data structure is in realtimedb > post > {uid:{time:{caption:"caption}}}
                        (Object.values(data)).forEach((e)=>{
                                (Object.values(e)).forEach((p)=>{
                                    captions.unshift(p.caption)
                                })
                        });
                       
                                setpostdata(captions)
                });
     
        },[])
        // make  Post components
            const postRender = postdata.map((e)=>{
                return<>
                <Post caption={e}/>
                </>
            })


   
    return (
        <div className='HomeFeed'>
                <HomeReels  />
                <CreatePost />
               {postRender}
        </div>
    )
}
```

### post.js

uses caption as post data and receive it as props

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Add some state variable to make sure the loading process is completed. mount your component after that

Answer (score 1):

This commented out line is actually how you're supposed to do this:

```
// const [postdatabeforeload, setpostdatabeforeload] = useState([])
```

Without `useState` or `setState` your rendering code runs before the data is loaded from the database, so it renders the empty array you set initially: `var postdata=[]`.

By using `useState`/`setState` you tell ReactJS that the data has changed, and that triggers it to rerender the UI with the updated state.

So something like:

```
const [postdata, setpostdata] = useState([])

const starCountRef = ref(realtimedb, 'Posts/');
useEffect(() => {
  onValue(starCountRef, async (snapshot) => {
    const captions = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => { 
        captions.push(child.val().caption);
    });
    setpostdata(data)
  });
}, [])
```

Until the `useEffect` has execute, your `postdata` will have its default value of `[]`, as that's what you specify here `[postdata, setpostdata] = useState([])`.

Then once the data has loaded, you'll get the array of captions.

Also see:

- [Initiate React components with data from Firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208033/initiate-react-components-with-data-from-firebase-database/64211296#64211296)
- [Retrieving items from firebase and dynamiccaly populating it in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766830/retrieving-items-from-firebase-and-dynamiccaly-populating-it-in-react-native/62767593#62767593)

Comment: the Problem is new data (Captions ) are added at the end, so old posts come at the top. I used unshift method instead of push, again old data doesn't change order.  Only newly added data does. so the order is (   previous loaded Data in Descending order, After that newly added Data in correct order)

Comment: The code I shared starts with an empty `captions` each time, precisely to prevent this problem from happening. Are you sure you used it as is?